# Merge with Pyspark

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with Pyspark, I have Spark 1.6. And I would like to group some values together.

```
+--------+-----+
|  Item  |value|
+--------+-----+
|  A     |  187|
|  B     |  200|
|  C     |    3|
|  D     |   10|
```

I would to group all item with less of 10% total value together (in this case C and D would be group into new value "Other")

So, the new table look like

```
+--------+-----+
|  Item  |value|
+--------+-----+
|  A     |  187|
|  B     |  200|
| Other  |   13|
```

Does some one know some function or simple way to do that?
Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the dataframe twice to get a dataframe with just the values you want to keep, and one with just the others.  Perform an aggregation on the others dataframe to sum them, then union the two dataframe back together.  Depending on the data you may want to persist the original dataframe before all this so that it doesn't need to be evaluated twice.

Comment: Thanks, your answer will be verry helpful.